# Scrollable DataTable with Auto Height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alloy-ui

[Alloy UI's DataTable](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/DataTable.Scrollable.html) provides a `scrollable` attribute to define `x` or `y` scrolling. This has to be used with a combination of a set `height` or `width`.

How can I have a table that will adjust to whatever the height/width of the window along with maintaining the `scrollable` feature?

Comment: I think [AUI-2088](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/AUI-2088) may need to be fixed for any of this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alloy UI API allows you to specify height & width in the px or round number. 
If you want to specify in the percentage, set the CSS property "width: 100%" for either the DataTable's table tag, or the div that contains the DataTable.

Example,

1. First, create a datatable.
2. Add the CSS attribute for width in percentage

*

```
var dataTable =  new Y.DataTable({
    id: 'mydata-table',
    footerView:   Y.FooterView,
    scrollable: "xy",
    height:'300px').render();

    $('#mydata-table').css('width', '80%');
    $('#mydata-table').css('height', '40%');
```

Please refer the [link](http://yuilibrary.com/forum-archive/forum/viewtopic.php@f=90&t=487.html) for detail.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code,** 
it worked for me in **mobile** as well as **desktop**.

```
container.find(".dataTables_scrollBody").css('height', container.height() - 20);
```

here the *container* is a `<div>` where the datatable is placed.

Comment: With v1.10.11 found also have to set the 'max-height' variable & run `table.settings()[0].oScroller.measure()` to recalculate page size for numbers display.